# sys.exit('message') isn't printing in IDLE

Tags: python-2.7, printing, message, exit, sys

In python IDLE it won't print the specified error message when using sys.exit('') but in cmd.exe it will. Why?

```
import sys

try:
    print fail
except:
    sys.exit("This is an example of an error message")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is printed to `stderr` which is not shown in IDLE because it's run in a subprocess (see this [report](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/129687/) of your observation and this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080958/python-idle-script-does-not-show-output-of-subprocess-but-cmd-exe-does)). So IDLE writes it on the terminal used to start IDLE.

The documentation states about the arguments of `sys.exit`:

> Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to
>   specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix
>   programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all
>   other kind of errors. If another type of object is passed, None is
>   equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is printed to stderr
>   and results in an exit code of 1. In particular, sys.exit("some error
>   message") is a quick way to exit a program when an error occurs.

So, the safest way is to only pass error codes and use an additional `print` (or calling a custom exit-function that gives the user an analysis of what happened).